# How can I use single quotes inside single quotes groovy Jenkinsfile?

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am running following the script from Jenkins(Jenkins file). it's working when I running from the terminal but not from Jenkins file. plz help

EX: `script { sh 'docker commit --change='CMD ["/bin/bash"]' test test:v1' }`

Comment: escape them with backslash `\'`

Answer (score 0):

Best way to handle this is by using ---

```
script { sh '''docker commit --change='CMD ["/bin/bash"]' test test:v1''' }
```

Works like a charm :)